# org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Could not get files The network name cannot be found

Tags: java, apache-camel, jcifs

I'm trying to copy some files from a local folder, to another local folder with Apache Camel JCIFS component.

Here is my Java code for MyRouteBuilder class:

```
package abc;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    public void configure() {
        long delay = 60 * 60 * 1000L;
        from("smb://otherUser@localhost/WORKGROUP/home/user/folder?password=secret&delay=" + delay)
        .to("file://home/otherUser/folder");

    // This doesn't work either:
    //from("smb://localhost;otherUser@localhost/WORKGROUP/home/user/folder?password=secret&delay=" + delay)
    //        .to("file://home/otherUser/folder");
    }
}
```

After executing this route, following exception appears:

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Could not get files The network name cannot be found.
at org.apacheextras.camel.component.jcifs.SmbOperations.listFiles(SmbOperations.java:345)
at org.apacheextras.camel.component.jcifs.SmbConsumer.pollDirectory(SmbConsumer.java:58)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:131)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: jcifs.smb.SmbException: The network name cannot be found.
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:563)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:663)
at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:176)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:911)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:954)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.resolveDfs(SmbFile.java:669)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:773)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doFindFirstNext(SmbFile.java:1986)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doEnum(SmbFile.java:1738)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.listFiles(SmbFile.java:1715)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.listFiles(SmbFile.java:1648)
at org.apacheextras.camel.component.jcifs.DefaultSmbClient.listFiles(DefaultSmbClient.java:161)
at org.apacheextras.camel.component.jcifs.SmbOperations.listFiles(SmbOperations.java:341)
... 11 more
```

Note 1: I have a samba server configured at my computer, and I'm sharing a simple folder with four files inside.

Note 2: I'm using localhost, just to test. After I get this working, I will use another machine IP/domain.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made it work. My route was wrong. It should be like this:

```
package abc;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    public void configure() {
        long delay = 60 * 60 * 1000L;
        from("smb://otherUser@localhost/folder?password=secret&delay=" + delay)
        .to("file://home/otherUser/folder");
    }
}
```

I noticed my error executing following command on a terminal:

```
smbclient -L localhost
```

That command gave me that Sharename was my shared folder "folder".